# NavigationBar alpha value changed automatically after dismissing view controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

**Weird thing**

- navigationbar'alpha value changes after dismissing view controller

**Step**

- Click button that presents a new viewcontroller

  - Set navigation bar alpha to 0.0 when the button is clicked
- Dismiss viewcontroller which I presented right before.

**Result [NG]**

- navigationbar'alpha value is set to 1.0

**Expected result**

- navigationbar's alpha should be 0.0 as expected

> Below sample is pretty much easy

**ViewController class**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s : %f", __func__,   self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s : %f", __func__, self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha);
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s : %f", __func__,  self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha);

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIButton *clickMe = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30)];
    [clickMe setTitle:@"clickme" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickMe setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickMe addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:clickMe];
 }


- (void)btnClicked {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
    second *sec = [[second alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**second class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    UIButton *getBack = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 40)];
    [getBack setTitle:@"getBack" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [getBack setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [getBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:getBack];
}

- (void)btnClicked {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I really would like to know what happened in this..
If someone knows this, let me know.. Thank you in advance.